# scanner skips double type numbers

Tags: java, input, double

Hello I'm new in java and as i was making a program practicing input/output methods I came to this error:

When I input a int value the program works well, but when I input a double value it shows me this:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class InpOutp
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);  // creates a scanner

        System.out.print("Enter price of a six-pack beer: ");
        double packPrice = in.nextDouble();

        System.out.print("Give the ml of a can: ");
        double canMl = in.nextDouble();

        final double CANS_PER_PACK = 6;
        double packMl = canMl * CANS_PER_PACK;

        // find the price per ml of a pack
        double pricePerMl = packPrice / packMl;
        System.out.printf("Price per ml: %8.3f", pricePerMl);
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using a comma as decimal point?

Comment: I just did it and it worked :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the separator. If you wish to use period try this

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in).useLocale(Locale.US);
```

EDIT:

Also it is worth to mention, you should use `in.nextLine();`
after every `nextInt()` or `nextDouble()` otherwise you will encoder problems with `nextLine` when entering text.

Try this

```
    System.out.print("Enter price of a six-pack beer: ");
    double packPrice = in.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("this will be skipped" +  in.nextLine());

    System.out.print("Give the ml of a can: ");
    double canMl = in.nextDouble();
    in.nextLine();
    System.out.print("And now you can type: ");
    System.out.println(in.nextLine());
```

Answer (score -1):

The fault was that I was typing the values with . (5.4) and I should type them with , (5,4).